# how do find the value of closeText option in a web page with java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to write a java script file that searches for `closeText` value and `console.log` it but i am a confused how to do this my approach is based on [this documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-closeText) but i can't figure out how to do this , i all get is an error `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

[my problem](https://RoastedAjarReentrant--five-nine.repl.co)

html.index file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe id=target ></iframe>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the script.js

```
var target = document.getElementById('target');


var closeText = $( ".selector" ).dialog( "option", "closeText" );


console.log(closeText);
```

Comment: [JQuery - $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)

Comment: have you defined jquery headers

Comment: how do you define jquery headers

Answer (score 3):

You need link JQuery before your code like bellow.

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script>
//your code here    
</script>
```

you can find your version of jquery from [here](https://code.jquery.com/)

Comment: I get a type error `TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function` please explain in detail what i am doing wrong

Comment: can you put your code here? because then we can get better understanding.

Comment: yes you need to import jquery ui after the jQuery.  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: For more details refer this link. https://jqueryui.com/dialog/   and https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: one more question can i use any jquery with any jquery-ui or i do i have to use the latest version

Comment: some versions are compatible with other versions, i can't say it exactly. Better if you can use latest versions.